# How to convert inside some files upper Charater in lower character in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am under ubuntu and I would know how is possible to convert inside a directory and sub directory all the UPPER caracter in lower caracter.

Tk

ex

```
HEADING_TITLE = Administration
TABLE_HEADING_ADMINISTRATORS = Pseudonymes
```

become

```
heading_title = Administration
table_heading_administrators = Pseudonymes
```

Comment: @JNevill, the OP does not want to convert **all** the uppercase.

Comment: @glennjackman That's true based on the example, but based on OP's question " all the UPPER caracter in lower caracter."...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To lower-case the first sequence of non-blank characters, with sed:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/\L&/' file
```

```
heading_title = Administration
table_heading_administrators = Pseudonymes
```

Comment: I do that sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/\L&/' *.txt  but it does'nt write inside the files.

Comment: Right. You can read the `sed` man page, specifically about the `-i` option.